# jquery .not() is not removing elements from jquery Object

Tags: jquery

I have a lengthy form in html, and some of the `<input>`'s have a class called `dependancy`.  I have a function that uses jQuery to select the `<form>` element.  Like so:

```
form = module.find('#formContainer').find('form');
```

`form` now contains an HTML , and I have ensured it contains it by outputting `form` to the console.  Now, I want to remove some elements contained within `form` that are of the class `dependancy`.  I figured I could use jQuery's .not() like so:

```
disabledFormElements = form.find('.dependency');
cleanForm = form.not(disabledFormElements);
```

When I output `disabledFormElements` to the console, it shows only the elements I want to remove.  Alas, the elements of class `dependancy` are not removed from `form`.  According to the jQuery documentation you can pass a variety of types to the .not() method and it should work.  Why might the .not() function not remove elements from the jQuery `form`?

I'm adding the HTML of the form to make it more clear:

```
<div id="formContainer">

<form id="customText" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="row equal-field-heights">
    <div class="four columns">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Is this for a Bar or Bat Mitzvah?</legend>
    <div class="four columns">
      <label for="radio1">
        <input class="dependency" name="gender" type="radio" id="radio1" value="m" checked onclick="changeGender('m')">Bar
      </label>

  </div>

  <div class="four columns">
    <label for="radio2">
  <input class="dependency" name="gender" type="radio" id="radio2" value="f" onclick="changeGender('f')">Female
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="as_he_she_steps" id="as_he_she_steps" value="he steps" />
  .
  .
  .
  .
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to actually remove the elements from the DOM (`remove()`) or to only exclude their references from the jQuery object (`not()`)?

Comment: Exclude their references from the jQuery object.  I'm not concerned about the DOM.  Thanks.

Comment: @Frederic for some reason your answers are now absent?  I saw them, but now they vanished.

Comment: Yup, when more than half of my answer is wrong, I tend to delete it before catching my breath and try to improve it. Helps the signal to noise ratio, IMHO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is that this:

```
form = module.find('#formContainer').find('form');
```

creates a jQuery object that contains only the actual `form` elements, not their descendants/children.  If there is just one form object in the formContainer, then this jQuery object only contains one DOM element.

So, when you try to remove items from that with `.not()`, nothing in the jQuery object is matched so nothing is removed.

If you want a jQuery object that contains all objects in the form, you could do this:

```
form = module.find("#formContainer form *");
```

And, if you wanted to then remove all items that match your class, you could do this:

```
form = module.find("#formContainer form *").not(".dependancy");
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It is only retrieving a single DOM element.  I am selecting the form with that code because eventually in my script I am applying a method to that elements called .serializeObject() which will serialize the form.  But I don't want it to serialize elements that are or a specific class.

Comment: @ariestav - If the serialize code just takes a parent form element, then you will have to either physically remove the `.dependancy` elements from the DOM before calling serialize or you will have to modify the serialize to skip the desired elements.  You can't fix it the way you were trying to.  In the future, it's much better to describe your real problem in your quesiton so we can be sure to help you with that.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  You are right, and please accept my apology for not being clear in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to select except the `.dependancy` class elements.

```
cleanForm = form.not(".dependancy");
```

If above code wouldn't work try this:

```
cleanForm = $(form).not(".dependancy");
```

Or Alternately use this:

```
cleanForm = $(form).find(":not(.dependancy)");
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Kundan,  I tried the first and second suggestion and when I output `cleanForm` to the console, I still see the elements of the class `dependency`.  And I did update the spelling of `dependancy` to `depenedency`

Answer (score 0):

[not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filters out the elements matched by its argument and builds a *new* jQuery object from the remaining elements. It does not modify the original jQuery object in-place.

My original answer was misguided, as passing the result of `find()` to `not()` will always return a jQuery object with the same contents as the original, since [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns descendant elements which are not part of the original set in our case.

I would suggest you use the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to match the `<form>` element you're looking for in one go:

```
var form = module.find("#formContainer form:not(.dependency)");
```

Comment: I tried `cleanForm = form.not('.dependancy');` and it still contains the `.dependancy` elements when i output `cleanForm` to the console.

Comment: @ariestav, try the single selector in my updated answer. What does it give you? *(Note I substituted the correct `dependency` instead of `dependancy`.)*

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
module.find('#formContainer').find('form').each(function(i, f){
    form = $(f);
    form.html(form.children().not(".dependancy"));
});
```